# How to run together python3.10 and python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code which is written with python3.7
Because of python3.7 doesnt have switch-case I wrote another code script with python3.10
I need to run these two code snippets together. I dont know how to do it due to version difference. I cannot change the code with python3.7 because it has pysnmp and it runs only 3.7 version.
I run my first code with python3.7 like: python3 test.py
But python3.10 code it doesnt work.
Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Use virtual environments or official docker images of Python (mount the source code if you want to test the same code).

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Check this: https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/. In general, google for "run different python versions for development" and explore.

Comment: Since you depend on Python 3.7 don't use `match` control structures. Refactor your code to use another form of control flow instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot change the code with python3.7 because it has pysnmp and it runs only 3.7 version.

The original version of pysnmp is not supported anymore (due to [unfortunate circumstances](https://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-discuss/2022-August/030062.html)), and a maintained fork is now available as [pysnmplib](https://pypi.org/project/pysnmplib/). This version supports Python >= 3.8. Using that instead will allow you to run everything on 3.10.